# Telerik RadListView TextView click on row with Swipe Action

Tags: android, listview, telerik

I have a Telerik RadListView. 
Row - just some textview.
in adapter I make

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewHolder holder, int position) {
  holder.tv.setOnClickListener(....);
}
```

Everything work fine until I don't start use SwipeContent.

```
@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateSwipeContentHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    View swipeContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_emails_listview, viewGroup, false);
    SwipeEmailViewHolder vh = new SwipeEmailViewHolder(swipeContentView);
    return vh;
}
@Override
public void onBindSwipeContentHolder(final ListViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
....
}
```

After that OnClick method doesn't call for textview. Seems that onclick action passes to swipe layout but dosn't pass to listview row layout....

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tvTest;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvTest = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
        tvTest.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        switch(id){
        case R.id.tv_test: //do some stuff
                          break; 
        }
    }
}
```

and set below  in xml.

> android:clickable="true"

Comment: doesn't help :(